# Is function invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, functions

Reflection on the unit circle:

Let $E=\mathbb R ^{2} - \left\{0,0\right\} $ be perforated plane and $f: E \mapsto E$ defined by $f\left(x,y\right)=\left(\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}  }  , \frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}  }   \right) 
$

Show with Jacobian matrix that $f$ is in all points local invertible. Show that $f$ is also global invertible. Find $f^{-1}$ and explain mapping geometrically.

What I did:

I started with determinante of Jacobian matrix to show that function is local invertible, but I got the following result.

Is that enough for showing that function is local invertible? How do I do rest?

$Df=\frac{-x^{4}-y^{4}-2x^{2}y^{2}    }{\left(x^{2}+y^{2}  \right) ^{2} } $

Comment: The determinant of the Jacobian matrix should be: $\det Df = \frac{-x^4 - y^4 - 2x^2y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^4}$ which simplifies to: $-\frac1{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$ (which shows that $f$ is locally invertible everywhere)

Comment: Thanks. But how can I show is it global invertible? Should I just show that is injective or?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic While both egreg and Ahmed give excellent and complimentary answers below, they don't really answer the general question of when a locally invertable function is globally invertable on $\mathbb R^n$. In general,the question is not easy to answer. To that end, I think this answer will be helpful.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41551/global-invertibility-of-a-map-mathbbrn-to-mathbbrn-from-everywhere-loc

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 I vaguely remember that for an exam in Higher Analysis I had to discuss a paper about a “global inversion theorem”, but I don't remember the details: some years have passed. I surely have my notes somewhere, though.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to show that $f\circ f(\mathbf x) = \mathbf x, f(\mathbf x) = f^{-1}(\mathbf x),$ and $f$ is invertable?

Answer (score 1):

See the comment on the question for local invertibility.

Now, we prove that $f$ is invertible by showing that $f$ is one-one and onto. Given $(x_1, y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in \Bbb R^2 - \{(0,0)\}$, we have:

$$f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_2, y_2) \implies \begin{cases} \frac{x_1}{x_1 ^2 + y_1^2} = \frac{x_2}{x_2 ^2 + y_2^2} \\ \frac{y_1}{x_1 ^2 + y_1^2} = \frac{y_2}{x_2 ^2 + y_2^2}\end{cases}$$

Squaring the equations and adding them to each other, we get $x_1^2 + y_1^2 = x_2^2 + y_2^2$, which then given $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 = y_2$.

Next, given $(X,Y) \in \Bbb R^2 - \{(0,0)\}$, we want to find $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) = (X,Y)$, so we are solving for $x$ and $y$:

$$\begin{cases} X = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} \\ Y = \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} \end{cases}$$

Notice then that $X^2 + Y^2 = \frac1{x^2 + y^2}$

**Edit**

Now, on one hand, $X = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}$ gives (after cross multiplying) $x = X(x^2 + y^2)$, but $x^2 + y^2 = \frac1{X^2 + Y^2}$ (by taking reciprocals in the equation right above "Edit"), therefore:

$$x = X \times \frac{1}{X^2 + Y^2} = \frac{X}{X^2 + Y^2}$$

Similarly, we get:

$$y = \frac{Y}{X^2 + Y^2}$$

Comment: +1 for an excellent and elementary answer that doesn't use too sophisticated machinery.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I just dont understand last step, how to get x and y from previous step?

Comment: @Ahmed can you please just shortly explain, how to get at the end x and y?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic sorry for taking too much to reply. I was a little bit busy and I did not check my inbox until now. I hope this explanation makes things clear.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can see $f$ as a map $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, with
$$
f(z)=\frac{z}{|z|^2}=\frac{1}{\bar{z}}
$$
by considering $z=x+iy$ and so
$$
f(f(z))=f(\bar{z}^{-1})=z
$$
Therefore $f$ is the inverse of itself.

The map is the *circular inversion*: the points $O(0,0)$, $P$ and $P'=f(P)$ are aligned and $OP\cdot OP'=1$.

The computation of the Jacobian is easy. Let $f_1(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $f_2(x,y)=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$; then
$$
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}=\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\qquad
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}=-\frac{2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}=-\frac{2x}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
\qquad
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}=
\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$
so the Jacobian is
$$
-\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^4}(x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4)=-\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^2}
$$

Comment: +1 for a very good simplification using complex variables!

Answer (score 0):

The mapping $f$ is indeed reflection in the unit circle. In polar coordinates, the point $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ is mapped by $f$ to the new point 
$$
\left(\frac{r\cos\theta}{r^2},\frac{r\sin\theta}{r^2}\right)=\left(\frac1r\cos\theta,\frac1r\sin\theta\right).$$
Geometrically, $f$ sends $(x,y)$ to a new point with the same argument (angle), but distance $\frac1r$ from the origin instead of $r$. Geometrically it is clear that this map is invertible, because you can recover the original point by applying $f$ once more. So $f^{-1}=f$.

Comment: Hmmm.I'm not sure if the OP's professor would accept that as a rigorous answer-although it's true and gives good insight into WHY it's globally invertable.And by the way,isn't it actually a glide reflection in the unit circle due to the factor of $\frac{1}{r}$ in the polar expression? It may not be shifted,I really should work it out for myself,but I'm busy with a blog post right now.....lol

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Agreed this answer is not rigorous; it's responding to the OP's request "explain mapping geometrically"....