# Theorem regarding Change of Variables in finite dimesnion

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, constructive-mathematics

My question is based on  [Change of Variables in Multiple Integrals II
Peter D. Lax](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2695524?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)  > It is not necessary to read the paper before answering this question.The author tried to prove change of variables formula using elementary method but turns out to be buried in complexity.

My question is essentially theorem 2(on this post)

To ask my question , I will first state and prove the obvious result in one-dimension:

$$\quad \epsilon>0, n>0,x \in R,[a b] \subset R,b>a,y:R->R$$

> **Theorem 1**: Given any continuously differentiable function $y(x)$  and if $\frac{dy}{dx}>0 $ for $x \in [a, b]$: Then there exists a variable $\varphi_n$, and $\varphi_n(x)$ is continuously differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:
>
> i.  $|\varphi_n(x)-y(x)| \le \epsilon$ for $x \in (a, b)$
>
> ii. $\varphi_n(x)=x$ for sufficiently large $|x|$
>
> iii. $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto 0}\varphi_n(x)=y$ and $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto 0}\frac{d\varphi_n}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}>0$ for $x \in (a,  b)$
>
> iv. The mapping $\varphi:x\to R$ is one-to-one, so it is invertible

*Proof*:

$r(x)=-{\frac {n}{x^2-a^2}}$

$h(x)=-{\frac {n}{b^2-x^2}}$

$\psi_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{r(x)+h(x)},  & \text{if $a <x< b$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

define $\varphi_n=x(1-e^{-nx^2})+\psi_n(x) y(x)+\int_{-\infty}^x2nt(\frac{-1}{(t^2-a^2)^2}+\frac{1}{(b^2-t^2)^2})\psi_n(t)y(t)dt$

it is easily seen $\frac{d\varphi_n}{dx}=(1-e^{-nx^2})+2nx^2e^{-nx^2}+\psi_n(x)\frac{dy}{dx}$

all the terms on the right hand side are greater than zero

Taking limits and using inverse function theorem in one dimension, the theorem follows

> **Theorem 2**: $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$, $x \in R^N$, $y=f(x)$, $y=[y_1(x), y_2(x),y_3(x),..y_N(x)]$,  $x=[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N]$, and the the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of $y$ denoted as $\det J$ . Under what conditions can we always find a conitnuously differentiable $\varphi_n: \mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$ such that:
>
> i. $|\varphi_n(x)-y(x)| \le \epsilon$ inside some bounded region A
>
> ii. $\varphi_n(x)=x$ for sufficiently large norm $|x|$
>
> iii. $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto 0}\varphi_n(x)=y$ and $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto 0}\det J_n =\det J$ inside some bounded region  and $|\det J_n|>0$ for all $x$,where $\det J_n$ is determinant of Jacobian matrix of $\varphi_n(x)$ ?

This is of practical importance because if the above properties are satsified by $\varphi_n$, then according to [Hadamard's global inverse function theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41551/global-invertibility-of-a-map-mathbbrn-to-mathbbrn-from-everywhere-loc)  then the mapping $\varphi_n :R^N->R^N$ is  globally bijective.

Comment: @Anton Grudkin thanks for your suggestions

Comment: you are welocme!

Comment: $n$ is an odd choice for a continuous parameter. Also you need to mention $\epsilon$ in the hypotheses; not a good idea to have it in the conclusion without identifying it at the beginning.

Comment: Is the $f$ in Thm. 2 continuously differentiable?

Comment: @zhw. yes you can assume it to be.

Comment: @zhw. you can also take $n=1/m$ where $m \in N$ and $N$ set of natural numbers. so if you dont like n you can replace it with $m$ and $m->\infty$

Comment: Without making some assumptions on $ y (x) $, I  realised theorem 2 not true in general.

Comment: But the conditions I'm yet to find.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer (also too long for a comment I guess) but what I was only able to do:

$i \in N$

$a_i<b_i$

$n>0,\epsilon>0,\delta>0$

$r(x_i)=-{\frac {n}{x_i^2-a_i^2}}$

$h(x_i)=-{\frac {n}{b_i^2-x_i^2}}$

$\psi(x_i) =
\begin{cases}
e^{r(x_i)+h(x_i)},  & \text{if $a_i <x_i< b_i$ } \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

$A_i=${$x: a_i <x_i< b_i$}

$A=\bigcap_{i=1}^N A_i$

$z^2=\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2$

$p_i(x)=\psi(x_1)\psi(x_2)\psi(x_3)...\psi(x_N)y_i(x)$

$p_i(x)=0$ for $x \notin A$

$g_i(x)=x_i(1-e^{-nz^2})$

$\phi_i(x)=p_i(x)+g_i(x)$

$\varphi_n(x)=[\phi_1(x),\phi_2(x),\phi_3(x),...\phi_N(x)]$

$p_n(x)=[p_1(x),p_2(x),p_3(x),...p_N(x)]$

$g_n(x)=[g_1(x),g_2(x),g_3(x),...g_N(x)]$

$J,J_{p_n},J_{g_n},J_{\varphi_n}$ denote the Jacobian Matrix of $y(x),p_{n}(x),g_{n}(x),\varphi_n(x)$ respectively

I was able to show $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto 0}\varphi_n(x)=y(x)$ for every $x \in A$ and $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto 0}|detJ_{\varphi_n}|=|detJ|$ for every $x \in A$

and for sufficiently large $|x|$ i.e large $|z|$, $\varphi_n(x)=x$

Using [Matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), I was able to show $detJ_{\varphi_n}=detJ_{g_n}>0$ for $x \notin A$

I was also able to show for sufficiently small $n$ ,

$\mu^*(A \bigcap B) \le \epsilon$

where $B=${x:$|detJ_{\varphi_n}|=0$}

How can I fix my $\varphi_n(x)$ so that it maintains all the stated properties and $|detJ_{\varphi_n}|>0$ for all $x$ ?

Comment: +1 for working on your problem, though I admit I personally am useless here.