# Proper map on $n$-sphere

Tags: general-topology, limits, spheres

[Proper functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map) are defined over topological spaces.

For functions $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ the conditions ["simplify"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41551/global-invertibility-of-a-map-mathbbrn-to-mathbbrn-from-everywhere-loc) to $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}|f(x)|=\infty$.

Are similar "simplications" know for functions over the [n-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) $S^{d}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{d+1} \mid \|x\|=1\}$, i.e., $f:S^{d}\rightarrow S^{d}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A function $f$ from $\mathbb{S}^d$ to itself is proper iff it is
> continuous.

Note that
$\mathbb{S}^d$ is compact and so every closed subset of it is compact and viceversa

- Continuous$\rightarrow$ proper.
  Every continuous function $f:\mathbb{S}^d\to \mathbb{S}^d$ is proper, since $f^{-1}$ sends closed (=compact) sets to closed (=compact) sets.
- Proper $\rightarrow$ continuous. Every proper function $f:\mathbb{S}^d\to \mathbb{S}^d$ is such that $f^{-1}$ sends compact (=closed) sets to compact (=closed) sets. This is one of the possible definition of continuity

The result is true in a more general form: given an Hausdorff compact space $X$, $f:X\to X$ is proper iff it is continuous,