# A linear combination of diffeomorphims still a diffeomorphism?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, linear-transformations, jacobian, diffeomorphism

Let $G_1, ..., G_s : \mathbb{R}^s \to \mathbb{R}^s$ be diffeomorphisms on an open unit ball $B \subset \mathbb{R}^s$, centered at $0$, onto their images. Let $m_1, .., m_s$ be integers not all $0$, and let $F = m_1 G_1 + ... + m_s G_s$.
Suppose we know that the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of $F$ at $x$ is non-zero for all $x \in B$.

1. Does it then follow that $F$ is still a diffeomorphism on $B$?
2. If $F$ is not a diffeomorphism on $B$, is it possible to show that
   $$
   \# F^{-1}(y) < C
   $$
   for all $y$ in $F(B)$ for some positive $C$?

Any comments are appreciated!

Ps edits had been made based on comments

Comment: I think 1 admits an easy counterexample. Take $F = G - G = 0$ for any diffeo $G$.

Comment: I was hoping that the assumption that the Jacobian of $F$ at $0$ is non-zero would remove easy counterexamples...

Comment: Is that in the OP? If you know the jacobian is non-zero, you have that $F$ is a local diffeo and hence has discrete fibers. The question is whether there's a uniform, finite bound on the fibers, right?

Comment: Sorry I meant to write the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of $F$ is non-zero. Typos had been corrected. I hope it's clearer now, thank you!

Comment: I liked the previous version of the question more. You are right, the Jacobian condition at a single point rules out the trivial counterexamples. For example, for $F=G-G$ we have $dF(0)=0$, obviously. You posed a good question. This version is also interesting, though.

Comment: thank you! I am still curious about the previous version, but I thought I should ask a more easier question first and try thinking about it

Comment: The $m_i$ are irrelevant because $m_iG_i$ is a diffeomorphism if $G_i$ is one.

Comment: @Paul, also if (1) holds for two diffeos, it holds for $n$, by induction.

Comment: It looks like (1) holds if $F$ is proper and the image is simply connected by a result by Hadamard https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41551/global-invertibility-of-a-map-mathbbrn-to-mathbbrn-from-everywhere-loc?noredirect=1&lq=1 Although it's not clear to me if these conditions will be satisfied automatically in my situation...