A smooth mapping with bounded inverse of derivative is a bijection in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth mapping satisfying:

the matrix $f^\prime(x)$ is nonsingular at every point
$x\in\mathbb{R}^n$

$\|(f^\prime)^{-1}(x)\|<C$ with a constant $C$ that is independent
of $x$.


Show that $f$ is a bijective mapping.

This is an exercise I met when reading Zorich's Mathematical Analysis (Section 10.7).
I am supposed to show that $f$ is both injective and surjective.
It is easy to see that when $n=1$ the proposition is right since $f'(x)$ will not change its sign in this situation. But this method turns invalid when $n\ge 2$. I have to try in other way.

Injective: Suppose that $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R^n}, f(x_1) = f(x_2), x_1 \neq x_2 $, then I constructed a function
$$
\phi_v(t) = \langle f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2),v \rangle
$$
for some $v \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and tried to obtain a contradiction to condition 1. by taking derivative
$$
\phi_v^\prime(t) = 2 \langle f^\prime(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)(x_1-x_2),v\rangle.
$$
Now since $\phi_v(0) = \phi_v(1)$, by Rolle's theorem we see that
$$
0=\phi_v^\prime(\eta_v) = 2 \langle f^\prime(\eta_v x_1+(1-\eta_v)x_2)(x_1-x_2),v \rangle.
$$
Unfortunately this leads to no contradiction.

Surjection: Suppose that $y_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}$. I tried to use the contraction mapping principle to find a $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = y_0$ by constructing a function
$$
g_{y_0}(x) = A(x)(f(x)-y_0) + x
$$
where $A(x)$ is something invertible.
Now
$$\begin{aligned}
||g_{y_0}^\prime(x)|| 
&= ||A^\prime(x)(f(x)-y_0) + A(x)f^\prime(x) + I|| \\
&\leq ||(f^\prime)^{-1}(x)A^\prime(x)(f(x)-y_0) + A(x) + (f^\prime)^{-1}(x)||||f^\prime(x)||.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now I have no more idea about how to choose a proper $A(x)$.



Note that the function $f[z)=e^z$ shows that you will need to invoke the second hypothesis to prove injectivity.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41551/571974 might be relevant.

Because $f'(x)$ is nonsingular at every points $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ is a local homeomorphism by the inverse function theorem. If we can prove that $f$ is actually a covering map, then by algebraic topology, $f$ is a homeomorphism since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is simply connected.
I mainly follow the proof in [Berger, Nonlinearity and functional analysis, Theorem 5.1.5 (Hadamard)].

Lemma: $f$ lifts line segments, i.e., for any finite line segment joining $y_0=f(x_0)$ and $y_1\in \mathbb{R}^n$ for any $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$, there is a curve $x(t)$ such that $f(x(t))=ty_1+(1-t)y_0$ with $x(0)=x_0$.
Proof: We seek a curve $x(t)$ such that $f(x(t))=ty_1+(1-t)y_0$.  since $f$ is a local homeomorphism, $x(t)$ exists for small $t$. Let $\beta$ be the largest number such that $x(t)$ can be continuously extended to $0\leq t <\beta$ satisfying $f(x(t))=ty_1+(1-t)y_0$. We shall prove that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\beta}x(t)$ exists. Assuming this fact for the moment, $x(t)$ can be continuously extended to $t=\beta$ by the continuity of $f$. By virtue of the fact that $f$ is a local homeomorphism, $x(t)$ can be continuously extended for $t>\beta$.
This contradicts the maximality of $\beta$, and we conclude that $x(t)$ exists for $t\in[0,1]$. So $f$ lifts line segments.
Consequently, we only need to prove that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\beta}x(t)$ exists. If  $t<\beta$, $x(t)$ satisfies the equation $$x'(t)=[f'(x(t))]^{-1}(y_1-y_0),$$ so that for any $t_1, t_2<\beta$, $$\|x(t_2)-x(t_1)\|\leq\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\|x'(t)\|dt\leq C\|y_1-y_0\||t_2-t_1|.$$
Thus $x(t)$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition for $t< \beta$ and since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is complete, $\lim_{t\rightarrow \beta}x(t)$ exists.
$\blacksquare$

By this lemma, we know that $f$ is a surjective local homeomorphism. Because $f$ can lift line segments, $f$ is a covering map according to [Berger, Nonlinearity and functional analysis, 5.1.1].
